# Riemann–Von Mangoldt formula

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $$N(T) = \#\{\rho \in \mathbb{C}: \zeta(\rho) = 0,\, \operatorname{Im} \rho \in (0,T]\}$$ denote the number of zeros of $\zeta(s)$, counting multiplicities, with imaginary part lying in the interval $(0,T]$,  that is, with imaginary part greater than $0$ and less than or equal to $T$.  For example, one has $N(50) = 10$, since there are exactly 10 zeros of $\zeta(s)$ with  imaginary part lying in the interval $(0,50]$.  The **Riemann–von Mangoldt formula**,  conjectured by Riemann in 1859 and proved by von Mangoldt in 1905, states that
$$N(T)={\frac  {T}{2\pi }}\log {{\frac  {T}{2\pi }}}-{\frac  {T}{2\pi }}+O(\log {T}) \qquad (T \to \infty),$$ or, equivalently,
$$N(2 \pi T)=T \log T-T+O(\log {T}) \qquad (T \to \infty).$$
I'm wondering if more is known.  In particular, is there a known asymptotic expansion of $N(T)$ or $N(2 \pi T)$, or, perhaps even, an explicit formula?  (Pardon if there is an obvious reference for this.  I've been working in analytic number theory for only the last few years, and there are still some gaps in my knowledge that I'm trying to fill.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure why my answer received negative votes. I think it's correct.  Someone please point out my errors?

EDITED TO REFLECT @LUCIA'S COMMENTS: After digging through a bunch of references, I sorted out the answer I was looking for.  For all $T > 0$ except at the points of discontinuity of $N(2\pi T)$, one has
$$N(2 \pi T) =1+ \frac{1}{\pi} \theta(2\pi T) + \frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{Arg}\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\pi i T\right)+2R(T),$$
where $\operatorname{Arg}$ is the principal branch of the argument, where $\theta(T)$ is the Riemann-Siegel theta function, and where $R(T)$ is an integer that is $O(\log T)$.  According to p. 98 of Davenport's book, you can get rid of the $R(T)$ integer term by replacing the principal value of $\arg \zeta(1/2+2 \pi i T)$ with the variation of $\arg \zeta(s)$ from $s = +\infty+2\pi iT$ to $1/2+2 \pi iT$ starting with value $0$, as long as  $T$ is not $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ times an ordinate of a zero of $\zeta(s)$.

By a known asymptotic expansion of $\theta(t)$, one has the asymptotic relation
\begin{align*}
N(2 \pi T) & =T \log T-T+\frac{7}{8}+\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{Arg}\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\pi i T\right)+2R(T)+O\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)  \\
& =   \int_1^T \log t \, dt -\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{Arg}\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\pi i T\right)+2R(T)+O\left(\frac{1}{T}\right) 
\end{align*}
and the asymptotic expansion
\begin{align*}
N(2 \pi T)  - \frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{Arg}\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\pi i T\right)   \sim T \log T - T+ 2R(T) + \frac{7}{8}+\frac{1}{96 \pi^2 T}+ \frac{7}{11340\pi^4 T^3}+ \frac{31}{161280 \pi^6 T^5}+\cdots
\end{align*}
as $T \to \infty$, where the numerators and (1/2)denominators are as in OEIS Sequences A036282 and A114721, respectively.  Here is a plot of the function $N(2\pi T)$ and its smooth approximation  $1+\frac{1}{\pi}\theta(2\pi T)$.

[image]

Comment: The argument here is defined by continuous variation along straight lines from $2$ to $2+iT$ to $1/2+it$.  I don't know why you call this the principal branch.  I would not rely on the arxiv paper by physicists, but please read Davenport carefully.

Comment: Davenport says also by continuous variation from $+\infty+iT$ to $1/2+iT$, which should be the same as $\operatorname{Arg}\zeta(1/2+iT)$ as long as $T$ isn't the imaginary part of a zero of $\zeta(T)$.  Can you give a counterexample to this claim?  Also, Davenport doesn't mention the Riemann-Siegel theta function $\theta(t)$, so obviously he isn't the last word on the subject.  Riemann never proved the asymptotic for $N(T)$, but that didn't detract from its being true.  Obviously there's a lot more going on here than is noted in Davenport.

Comment: Obviously, the argument needs to jump up by $\pi$ for every zero ordinate on the critical line, but it also has to jump at potential zeros off of the critical line; so at least the Riemann Hypothesis should imply that my statement is correct, as I doubt that $\zeta(s+iT)$ has any winding numbers as $s \to 1/2$ from $\infty$ if $T$ is not an imaginary part of a zero of $\zeta(s)$.  Is this wrong?  I will continue to be mystified by Davenport's explanation until someone shows me the precise definition of $\Delta_C \arg$....

Comment: E.g., please write out an exact formula for $\Delta_L \arg \zeta(s)$, where $L$ is the line from $+\infty+iT$ to $1/2+iT$.

Comment: $\Delta_C \arg$ is not in Davenport's index of notation, and I can't find it defined anywhere.  So when you say "read Davenport carefully," I say, either show me where he defines the notation or tell me how it is defined.  I've never seen it anywhere else.

Comment: By the way, the black curve I plotted is exactly the formula for $N(2\pi T)$ I gave, and it checks out to as far as I can compute in Mathematica.   And here is the non-arxiv version of the paper: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/102/10006

Comment: Just to understand what you're saying:  are you claiming that the difference between $N(2\pi T)$ and $\theta(2\pi T)/\pi$ is bounded?  That would be nonsense.

Comment: Please answer my question and write out an exact formula for $\Delta_L \operatorname{arg} \zeta(s)$, and please stop being disrespectful.  I'm trying to figure out what Davenport means by his notation.

Comment: The argument is defined to be zero at $s=2$.  Now consider the line joining $2$ to $2+iT$ and define the argument so that it is a continuous function on that line.  Finally go from $2+iT$ to $1/2+iT$ on the horizontal line, again defining the argument so that it is continuous on that line segment.  What you get will not in general be simply the principal value of $Arg \zeta(1/2+iT)$.  Why don't you answer my question on what you meant?  The argument defined in the correct way (as given here) is not a bounded function.

Comment: Or, as noted on p. 98, "or, equivalently, by continuous horizontal movement from $\infty+ iT$ to $1/2 + iT$, starting with the value $0$."  What do you do if you hit a  potential zero off the critical line?   Please give me an example where it is not the  principal value of $\arg \zeta(1/2+iT)$ where $T$ is not an imaginary part of a zero of $\zeta(s)$, and provide a reference that $\Delta_L \arg \zeta(s)$ is unbounded off those horizontal lines.  A charge of "nonsense" requires a reference or a proof.

Comment: E.g, what's the smallest value of $T$ for which the arguments are different?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you would be maintaining that $|S(t)| \le 1$ --- $S(t)$ is $1/\pi$ times the argument as usually defined in the literature.  The growth of this quantity is notoriously slow.  But look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00709.pdf which gives examples of large values of $S(t)$:  at the moment the numerical values are only about $3.3$ or so.  Of course it is well understood that this gets arbitrarily large.

Comment: OK, edited.  I need to add an integer correction term $R(T)$  that is $O(\log T)$, and then the result is $\frac{1}{\pi}S(T)$.  I still don't know how $\arg \zeta(x+iT)$ varies "continuously" as $x+iT$ passes over a potential zero of $\zeta(s)$ off the critical line (as $x$ passes from $2$ to $1/2$).  Do you add $\pi$ or subtract $\pi$?  Also, you have to divide those large $S(T)$ values by $\pi$ in my formula--they are just over $\pi$, which means the $R(T)$ values are probably $\pm 1$ in those cases, but Mathematica can't calculate out that far to confirm. I'd love to see a graph of $R(T)$.

Comment: I might be remembering incorrectly, but $S(T)$ is typically defined by $\frac{S(T^+) + S(T^-)}{2}$ whenever $T$ is the ordinate of a zero (including those that are not on the critical line). Hopefully this answers your question about how the argument jumps around zeroes (as it should)?

Comment: That makes sense as a definition.  Thank you.  Why is $S(T)$ continuous between such ordinates?

Comment: If there's no zero in between the horizontal lines, there's no obstruction to shifting the defining contour around. In particular, that means the branch of the logarithm you're on doesn't change.

Comment: Oh, use the fact that the imaginary part of $\operatorname{Log}\zeta(1/2+iT)$ is differentiable between such ordinates.

Comment: Exactly which formula did you plot? If you plot it further out I believe you'll find that it does not evaluate correctly (e.g. in the range $\left\{T,\frac{282.4}{2 \pi},\frac{282.5}{2 \pi}\right\}$ which is in the neighborhood of Gram point $g_{126}$ and zeta zero $ρ_{127}$ where the first violation of Gram's law occurs).

Comment: For example, see [this WolframAlpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7BT+Log%5BT%5D+-+T+%2B+7%2F8+%2B+1%2FPi+Arg%5BZeta%5B1%2F2+%2B+2+I+%5C%5BPi%5D+T%5D%5D%2C+1+%2B+1%2FPi+RiemannSiegelTheta%5B2+Pi+T%5D%7D%2C+%7BT%2C+282.4%2F%282+Pi%29%2C+282.5%2F%282+Pi%29%7D%5D).

Answer (score 15):

As $T\to\infty$, we have
$$
N(T) = \frac{T}{2\pi}\log\frac{T}{2\pi}-\frac{T}{2\pi}+\frac{7}{8}+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty}\mathrm{Im}\Big(-\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(\sigma+iT)\Big)d\sigma+O(T^{-1}).
$$
This is proved in Chapter 15 of Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory.  The error term $O(T^{-1})$ is a truncation for the asymptotic expansions for the arctan and gamma functions.  The contribution from the arctan function consists of lower order terms in a Taylor expansion, and the contribution from the gamma function consists of lower order terms in the Stirling expansion.

EDIT:  Because of the apparent lack of clarity regarding "arg" in this result, I replaced "$\arg \zeta(1/2+iT)$" with the corresponding integral, which should not be ambiguous.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks!  I don't have that book.  Can you give the whole expansion?  And is that the principal branch of arg?

Comment: I mean, is it possible to develop the $O(T^{-1})$ term further?

Comment: OK I found the book.  What does his $\Delta$ mean in the explicit formula $\pi N(T) = \Delta_L \operatorname{Arg} \xi(s)$?  I've searched and searched but can't find the definition of $\Delta$ anywhere.

Comment: @JesseElliott As I said in my answer, if you look at the proof, the $O(T^{-1})$ can be expanded further using the expansions for arctan (Taylor series) and gamma (lower order terms in Stirling's formula).

Comment: @JesseElliott People often write $\Delta$ to denote "change".  So when Davenport writes $2\pi N(T) = \Delta_R \arg\xi(s)$, the RHS means the change in argument of $\xi(s)$ as one traverses the rectangle $R$ (in the positive direction) with vertices $2$, $2+iT$, $-1+iT$, and $-1$.

Comment: That use of $\Delta$ is basically referring to the argument principle: if you want to count the number of zeros of an analytic function $f$ around a rectangle $R$, you integrate $f'/f$ once around the boundary counterclockwise (assuming $f$ itself is nonvanishing on $R$, which is a tricky issue when $f(s) = \zeta(s)$ and $R$ passes through the critical strip). In particular, $N(T)$ is counting zeros *with multiplicity* (since that is how the argument principle works). We expect all zeros of $\zeta(s)$ to be simple, but that's not proved or even known to follow from the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: @2734364041.  So $\Delta$ means integral?  If so, why don't they just write integrals?  Also, can you write out the series for me?  Because I can't figure out what it is from the Davenport book.  If you do I will accept your answer.  Also, Davenport writes $\pi N(T)$, not $2\pi N(T)$.

Comment: @JesseElliott Regarding $\pi$ vs. $2\pi$:  You're looking in a different part of the proof.  Look at the bottom of p. 97.  Regarding the notation $\Delta$:  Like I said, $\Delta$ denotes CHANGE IN ARGUMENT, which can be expressed as an integral (this is the argument principle).

Comment: (Sorry for the caps, I don't know how to italicize or embolden in the comments.)

Comment: So you are integrating the logarithmic derivative of the principal value of the argument of $\xi(s)$, but not dividing by $2 \pi$?  "Change in argument" has no precise meaning for me.  You mean something like in the total change theorem of calculus?  Is the $1/(2\pi i)$ in the operator expression for $\Delta$?

Comment: @JesseElliott https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VariationofArgument.html or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79-ESkh5_f0

Comment: I'm just asking about notation.  I know the argument principle, I was just wondering what is the precise definition of $\Delta$.  CHANGE IN ARGUMENT is not a definition, and nor does MathWorld define $\Delta$.  I guess you want me to reverse engineer the definition.

Comment: Never mind, I found a reference that writes out the full expansion and doesn't use undefined notation.

Comment: @2734364041.  If you replace the first non-integral terms with $1+\frac{1}{\pi}\theta(T)$, where $\theta$ is an equality, then you can get an exact formula for $N(T)$ for $T$ not an imaginary part of a zero of $\zeta(s)$.  Why not do that?  I'm not sure why may answer got downvotes.  The formula I gave is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to 2734364041's answer, [this paper of Tim Trudgian](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X13002047) may be useful: in particular, Trudgian shows that for all $T\geq e$,

$$\left|N(T)-\frac{T}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{T}{2\pi e}\right)-\frac{7}{8}\right|\leq 0.112\log T+0.278\log\log T+2.510+\frac{0.2}{T}$$

and also includes a useful discussion of all the terms that go into this result.

Comment: That other answer has a $T/(2\pi)$ term – did you leave one out of your formula?

Comment: Good pick up @GerryMyerson! I've fixed it now --- there is a factor of e in the denominator of the argument of the log, which is equivalent.

Comment: A few months ago, a paper was released that managed to further improve the bound. https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.06506

Answer (score 1):

You have also Guinand formula for $N(T)$, see, for example, in this answer
https://mathoverflow.net/a/104570/7402

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [blog](https://travorlzh.github.io/2021/01/19/zeta-zeros-count.html) years ago that derived the whole analytic expression. Specifically, we have

$$
N(T)={T\over2\pi}\log{T\over2\pi}-{T\over2\pi}+\frac78+S(T)+\frac1\pi\delta(T),
$$

where

$$
S(T)={1\over2\pi i}\left(\int_{\frac12-iT}^{2-iT}+\int_{2-iT}^{2+iT}+\int_{2+iT}^{\frac12+iT}\right){\zeta'\over\zeta}(s)\mathrm ds
$$

and

$$
\delta(T)=\frac T4\log\left(1+{1\over4T^2}\right)+\frac14\arctan\left(1\over2T\right)+\frac T2\int_0^\infty{x-\lfloor x\rfloor-\frac12\over(T/2)^2+(x+1/4)^2}\mathrm dx.
$$